# How to Interpolate Lat/Long Points (Route) between Two Lat Long Points

Tags: python, interpolation, latitude-longitude, linear-interpolation, geographic-distance

Lets say we have two addresses that are provided. I grabbed two random ones from the web below:

```
# Google headquarters:
google_lat = 37.422131
google_lon = -122.084801

# Apple headquarters
apple_lat = 37.33467267707233
apple_lon = -122.0089722675975
```

Now, lets say I'd like to interpolate a series of points between these two addresses. Maybe for starters a simple linear interpolation (or one that takes into account the spherical nature of the Earth) would work. In practice, a road route like provided via Google Maps would work if I could obtain an array of lat/longs for every n miles between each point. Might there be a REST API to obtain points between two addresses?

Just to get started on some ideas, how could I start approaching a task like this if I cannot go the API approach above? Bare minimum I would want is an array of lat/longs between each address with the points therein.

An example in Python would be nice but a language agnostic discussion is welcome too. Thanks.

Comment: Try the [GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/). There are several answered versions of this question there (e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8424/interpolate-points-between-coordinates-for-smooth-animation-in-google-maps-or-op)

Comment: You have to find points along a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) path. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17267162/355230) to a somewhat related question.

Answer (score 1):

You offered a pair of (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) locations,
with a line segment connecting them.

Compute a pair of deltas:

- delta_x = x2 - x1
- delta_y = y2 - y1

Now use parametric form of equation for line segment to interpolate.
Let `t` vary from 0 .. 1 in step sizes as small as you like,
and emit

```
(x1 + t * delta_x, y1 + t * delta_y)
```

for your interpolated points.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic linear interpolation example for starters.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Google headquarters:
google_lat = 37.422131
google_lon = -122.084801

# Apple headquarters
apple_lat = 37.33467267707233
apple_lon = -122.0089722675975

# latitude is the x-coordinate
# longitude is the y-coordinate
# lets say we wanted to figure out a series of points between the two given with linear interpolation

latitudes = np.linspace(apple_lat, google_lat, 10)  # ten points
longitudes = (google_lon - apple_lon)/(google_lat - apple_lat)*(latitudes - apple_lat) + apple_lon

ax.plot(latitudes, longitudes, marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel('Latitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Longitude')

for x, y in zip(latitudes, longitudes):
    print(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Points Between:

```
37.33467267707233 -122.0089722675975
37.34439026850873 -122.01739768230888
37.354107859945145 -122.02582309702028
37.36382545138155 -122.03424851173166
37.37354304281796 -122.04267392644306
37.38326063425437 -122.05109934115444
37.392978225690776 -122.05952475586584
37.40269581712718 -122.06795017057722
37.412413408563594 -122.07637558528862
37.422131 -122.084801
```

But like you said, you need to account for the curvature of the earth, which means there is an extra z-axis to deal with. This requires further research and more honing on your linear algebra skills as this will certainly require some sort of transform from the x-y plane to the three dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

Shapely may be a library worth looking into if you're going to be working a lot with geometries:

You can also project the points to a map, so that the earth's curvature is accounted for. Documentation on how that's done can be found [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#other-transformations).

```
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import interpolate
import numpy as np

# Google headquarters:
google_lat = 37.422131
google_lon = -122.084801

# Apple headquarters
apple_lat = 37.33467267707233
apple_lon = -122.0089722675975

google = Point(google_lat, google_lon)
apple = Point(apple_lat, apple_lon)

line = LineString([google, apple])

pts = []
for div in np.arange(0.1,1,0.1):
   pts.extend(line.interpolate(div, normalized=True).coords[:])

print(pts)
```

Output:

```
[(37.41338516770723, -122.07721812675975), (37.404639335414466, -122.0696352535195),
 (37.3958935031217, -122.06205238027925), (37.38714767082893, -122.054469507039),
 (37.37840183853616, -122.04688663379875), (37.369656006243396, -122.0393037605585),
 (37.36091017395063, -122.03172088731824), (37.35216434165786, -122.024138014078),
 (37.343418509365094, -122.01655514083775)]
```